# Linearity of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that for a transformation to be linear it must satisfy these two conditions:

$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$

$f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$

Why the transformation is called linear? What does being linear mean? Where the linearity comes from?

Answer (score 2):

The sum and the product of two number are linear operations. A linear application or transformation conserve these operation; the transformation of the sum is the sum of transformations; For why linear look at the transformation that correspond to a line in the plane; its a linear application.

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the fact that applications like $x \mapsto ax$ verify the conditions you mention. And such applications represent lines, therefore the term linear.